# Redirecting nginx to another server with apache2

Tags: nginx, redirect, apache2

I have been fiddling around with nginx for a while now and wanted to add a nextcloud server to it. I already use Gitlab and YouTrack as servers which run well if i just try to access them like domain.com/gitlab for gitlab and domain.com/youtrack for youtrack. Now I wanted to add nextcloud to it and wanted to access it with domain.com/nextcloud. I can enter that in the browser but I only get the local ip back.

For more information: I use nginx (VM) for redirecting the urls to the according VMs (I use VMs as servers). I used the location /nextcloud/ block for it as for the others but didn't have any success. Everytime I enter domain.com/nextcloud/ it redirects to the website BUT in the address search is entered for example 192.168.178.54/nextclout/

The Nextcloud server uses apache for listening on the port.

With that I am not able to access the Nextcloud website out of my local network. Can anyone help me with it? If some information are needed just tell me and I will try to add them.

Thank you for everything!~

Answer (score 0):

This isn't caused by nginx or Apache, but rather how DNS, which is working how it should. Your domain likely only has an Apex (or A) record for the nginx server ip, and obviously your Apache server is going to have a different ip. You could make another Apex record for the Apache server, but then both servers would have to forward traffic between the two depending on the path, as connecting computer will just choose one of the two records at random (This is known as a round robin dns and is used to build a very simple load balancer).

What you're looking to do should be implemented using subdomains instead ie, gitlab.domain.com, youtrack.domain.com, nextcloud.domain.com. Each subdomain would have its own Apex record, gitlab and youtrack pointing to the nginx ip, and nextcloud to the Apache server.

Paths are intended to be used as a navigation system to the proper page once the correct server has already been found.

Comment: the apache server as well as the nginx server are in the same local network which means I only have one global network address to provide for the domain. I simply use the nginx to route everyting with the proxy pass to the according local ip address. Example:
everything for domain.com/gitlab is routed to another VM in the local network
`nginx local ip: 192.168.178.40

gitlab local ip: 192.168.178.41

block used:
location /gitlab {
proxy_pass http://192.168.178.41
}`

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood, now I see what you're getting at. If this is only a problem with nginx, I think what you're looking for is the line `proxy_set_header Host $host;` [Here's the docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/#passing-request-headers). If that doesn't resolve your issue, it'd be really helpful if you put the nginx and apache configurations in the question.

Comment: Thanks this worked well. I just needed then to add the domain as trusted domain in the nextcloud config. For everyone who has maybe the same issue: Be sure to set the root directory for apache right. Otherwise it will give a site not found error.